# How to calculate an integral vector such as $A=\int_{-5}^0 \frac{1}{\left(x^2+2^2\right)^{3/2}} \,dx$ $\{-x,0\}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Why these integrals have different results ?: $A=\int_{-5}^0 \frac{1}{\left(x^2+2^2\right)^{3/2}} \,dx$ $\{-x,0\}$  and $B=\int_{-5}^0 \frac{-x}{\left(x^2+2^2\right)^{3/2}} \, dx$. Vector $\overset{\to }{u}=\{-x,0\}=-x\overset{\to }{i}+\overset{\to }{0j}$ . **In B, I introduced the component ${-x}$ of $\overset{\to }{u}$ into de Integral to then multiply by $\overset{\to }{i}$ , Is it mathematicaly right? or, How I must solve A?**

Evaluating in Mathematica these results are: $A=\left\{-\frac{5 x}{4 \sqrt{29}},0\right\}$ and $B=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{29}})$.  **(*it is $B=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{29}})\overset{\to }{i}$)**

EDIT:
in this example, it shows they are solving as I solved B:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8c8q.png)

Comment: The result for A is different because you multiplied by $x$ after doing the integration.

Comment: I mean, the integral multiply by a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t take the $x$ inside the integral when multiplying by a vector, as the integral is a scalar and must be evaluated independently. So $A\ne B$.
Consider $A$ as an indefinite integral first.
Substitute $x=2\tan y \implies dx = 2\sec^2 y dy $ in $A$ to get $$\int \frac{2\sec^2y}{8\sec^3 y} dy = \frac 14 \int \cos y dy = \frac 14\sin y + c = \frac{x/2}{4\sqrt{1+(x/2)^2}} + c = f(x)$$

Then, just evaluate $f(x)\big|_{-5}^0=A$ and then your answer would be $\big(- Ax,0\big ).$

Comment: Hi, but the image I updated , the example inserts the vector inside the Integral.

Comment: @FernandoAntoniaPonce That vector is already inside the integral.

Comment: I don't think so, basically is the same

Comment: Let me clear things up. You have evaluated $A$ by first doing the integral and *then* multiplying by $-x$ (like in my answer). You have evaluated $B$ by first bringing the vector inside the integral, then evaluating it. Only one of these two ways can be correct, and it’s up to you to choose which one you mean. Indeed, in your image example, they have followed the $B$ approach, so you should do the same. Then $A=B$ indeed.

Comment: So clear. Thanks